# How can read the data field in a transaction?

Tags: transactions

if im sending a transaction including a hex data, who can read it? Is it encrypted and only the receiver can read it? If not, everyone can read the data...

Answer (score 3):

Anyone can read it. The entire blockchain is public.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=HASH&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

response's input field is the corresponding hex data.